# Is existing_yourmodelhere_attributes native to rails or part of some gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I'm updating an old rails 2 app to rails 4. In the view there is a form field defined like this:

```
school[existing_address_attributes][666][city]
```

The model is updated as normal in the controller:

```
@school.update_attributes(params[:school])
```

The form works, and submits and saves properly, but I can't tell where existing_address_attributes is defined.

This seems to work similarly to nested attributes. Is this native to rails? Is it some gem? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably defined by `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  Check the [Rails 2 documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M001681).